# text box accepting numbers in browsers and ipad but not in android mobile

Tags: meteor, web

i have a following code in the keydown textbox event for my meteor app, this textbox is accepting the numbers, it is working in browsers and ipad, but not in android mobile phone. Not sure what is wrong?

```
'keydown .clsAmount':function(eve){
        var keyid=eve.which;
        //console.log("the key press for amount is:"+keyid);
        if((eve.which>47 && eve.which<58) || (eve.which>95 && eve.which<106)|| eve.which==8 || eve.which==9 || eve.which==13 || eve.which==110) {
            //console.log("its a number");  
        }else{
            alert("Not a number, Enter only numbers");
            $(eve.target).val('');
            eve.preventDefault();
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), this feature is deprecated:

> **Deprecated**
>
> This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>   Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps
>   using it may break at any time.

I suspect this is what's happening here. Try:

```
var keyid = eve.which | eve.keyCode;
```

Also, add some debug output on that value to see if and when it is undefined.